# How to slide the page only after video ends?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, razor, iframe

I have an iframe slider that is being called in jquery. 
Slider cshtml calls the pages and sets the interval for sliding them.

```html
<iframe id="slider" src="/doc_api/OpenTasks/DepsCA" </iframe>
<script>
  var pages = '@ViewBag.pages';
  var p = JSON.parse(pages.replace(/(&quot\;)/g, "\""));

  var i = 0;
  var mi = p.length - 1;

  setInterval(function() {
    i++;
    if (i > mi) {
      i = 0
    }
    var src = p[i];
    var video = document.getElementById('slider')
    if (video.onended == true) {
      $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: src,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function() {
          document.getElementById('slider').src = src;
        }
      });
    }
  }, 30000);
</script>
```

The MediaPlayer.cshtml contains the  tag that plays the video:

```
 <video class="embed-responsive-16by9" id="video" src=@ViewBag.name style="height:850px; width: auto; padding-left:10%;background-color:#F2F1F2" autoplay loop" />
```

How to make the slider sliding only after video ends (if page contains the video) and then continue sliding in every 30 sec again (if page doesn't contain any video)?